# How to properly test statements in setInterval() in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have this very simple code:

```
public async authenticate(username: string, password: string) {
    const authenticationResponse = await this.dataProvider.authenticate(username, password);

    if (authenticationResponse.result.code == 0) {
        //start interval for periodically checking authentication info
        this._authInfoIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
             this.getAuthInfo();
        }, 2000);
```

In my unit tests only line with this.getAuthInfo() is not concidered as covered. Is it somehow possible to test this? I have tried some approaches with jasmine.createSpy but nothing seemed to work (most likely because I was doing it wrong). Can someone please help me to get it right? Thanks

UPDATE: I tried something like this

```
it('should test interval somehow', () => {
  const intervalCallback = jasmine.createSpy("getAuthInfo");
  jasmine.clock().install();
  service.authenticate('username', 'password');
  jasmine.clock().tick(2001);
  expect(intervalCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

and test fails instantly with AuthenticationService should test interval somehow FAILED Expected spy getAuthInfo to have been called.

SOLUTION: I had to spyOn also on dataProvider so I got right response to actually reach that part of code with interval

```
  it('should test interval somehow', async () => {
    const intervalCallback = spyOn(service, 'getAuthInfo');
    spyOn(dataProvider, 'authenticate').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(authenticateMockResponse));
    jasmine.clock().install();
    await service.authenticate('username', 'password');
    jasmine.clock().tick(2001);
    expect(intervalCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: How exactly have you tried to use `jasmine.createSpy`?

Comment: See my update on original post

Comment: I tried to reproduced this, when I use `jasmine.creatSpy('getAuthInfo')`, the test scenario fails

Comment: When I use `spyOn(service, 'getAuthInfo')` instead, the test succeeds and the line is considered as covered.

Comment: Yes, it does, that is why am I asking what is wrong. :) Mine also fails instantly with AuthenticationService should test interval somehow FAILED Expected spy getAuthInfo to have been called.

Comment: You have to mention in the question that the test is failing. Currently it reads like the test is succeeding but the coverage is not correctly reported. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`jasmine.createSpy()` should be used for creating a bare spy object, see the [documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/api/4.5/jasmine.html#.createSpy). It doesn't have any connection to your service, it's not what you are looking for.

You want to spy a function on an existing object (in your case the `service`), for which you can use the [spyOn](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#spyOn) function.

```
it('should test interval somehow', () => {
  const intervalCallback = spyOn(service, 'getAuthInfo');
  jasmine.clock().install();
  service.authenticate('username', 'password');
  jasmine.clock().tick(2001);
  expect(intervalCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: I have copied your solution and it sadly does exactly what it did before: instantly FAILED with message Expected spy getAuthInfo to have been called. I have updated my original code so you have more context of the function. Maybe there is problem with that async part?

Answer (score -1):

In Angular, you can use the async and fakeAsync functions from the @angular/core/testing module to properly test statements within a setInterval() function.

First, you'll need to wrap your test in the fakeAsync function, which allows you to use the tick() function to advance the virtual time. Next, you'll need to wrap the code you want to test within the setInterval() function in an async function.